# How to convert this chm file to pdf?

Tags: pdf, calibre

I want to convert [a chm file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8nhvxs0yegkoddn/Voice__Data_Communications_Handbook%20by%20Bates.chm) to a pdf file.
Calibre's command ebook-convert `ebook-convert 1.chm 1.pdf` only converts the first 7 pages of the chm file into a pdf file, while the chm file has much more pages. How can I convert the whole chm file into a pdf file? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to SuperUser.

Comment: @dr01 Unless there is reason to believe otherwise, it seems safe to presume OP wants a solution that runs on Linux/Unix, not Windows. And Unix/Linux software is on-topic here.

Comment: @derobert - amen. we wouldn't close a question about firefox because it might also be applicable to a Microsoft machine. there's something to be said for a domain name.

Comment: Another excuse to not even try to answer a question. Answers get migrated too after all.

Comment: This is not a question about Linux/Unix system administration.  SuperUser is a much better fit, and it includes questions about Linux as well as Windows.